# Why do large blurry smudges appear on my brand new camera?

Tags: spots

blurry smudge in my photos- sample attached... 
SX700 Canon powershot.. it is not dust or finger print... 
novice photographer... 
hlp please[image: two photos attached showing blurry spots [![][1]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6DiT.jpg)

Comment: It looks like something on your sensor. Was it present on the very first image you took ? As your camera is new, you should take it back to the shop or send it for repair

Answer (score 6):

As per @Olivier's comment, if it's a brand new camera as you say, and you can't see anything on the outside of the lens, and it is doing a similar thing on every image, check the very first image file, 0001, if you downloaded and still have that, then it's almost certainly on the inside of the camera.

The Canon powershot SX700 doesn't have a removable lens, so `don't attempt to get inside it, as this will invalidate the warranty`.

I would suggest that you contact the place you bought it from in the first instance: if it was from a shop, take it back into the shop. Take with you a sample of the first or earliest image if you can, and also the receipt. If you bought it online, you may need to contact them via an online account to arrange a return before you post it back to them.

Depending on what country you're in, the contract is between you and the shop/online seller that you bought it from (the exchange of money and goods), therefore they would usually be your first point of call for any issues. Failing that, you should be able to register with Canon for support, by entering the serial number and purchase date.

Comment: I second the advice of not messing with the camera.  Warranty should cover defects of this kind.  If the place of purchase is giving you trouble, contact Canon with scans of your receipt attached, and any shop communication recorded down if possible.